# how to use two functions from same controller in single page route using get in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

Am trying to use two different functions from one controller in a single page route

```
Route::get('/cart','App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\CartController@index');
Route::get('/cart','App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\CartController@alldata');
```

But the problem is the function `alldata` works where the function `index` doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 GET routes with the same path.

```
Route::get('/cart','App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\CartController@index');
Route::get('/cart/all','App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\CartController@alldata');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/cart','App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\CartController@index');
Route::get('/cart','App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\CartController@alldata');
```

Try to manipulate your logic in `controller` rather than in `route` file.

Use conditional in controller function.

Answer (score 0):

The `/cart` route is overwritten by the `alldata()`. So the `alldata()` is calling instead of `index()`.

kindly remove the `alldata()`'s route and pass the data from `index()`.